# date-fns локализирует в родительном падеже (вместо именительного)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, date-fns

В документации есть именительный и родительный падежи, но как выбрать конкретно именительный, я не нашёл.

https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/src/locale/ru/_lib/localize/index.js — тут, в принципе, содержатся имена месяцев в именительном падеже, но почему используются в родительном — совсем неясно. Помогите разобраться..

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-violet-6nsdu)

```
import React from "react";
import "date-fns";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import ru from "date-fns/locale/ru";
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  KeyboardDatePicker
} from "@material-ui/pickers";

export default function App() {
  const date = new Date();

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils} locale={ru}>
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        disableToolbar
        autoOk
        label="Начало"
        variant="inline"
        format="dd.MM.yyyy"
        value={date}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: попробуйте format="dd.LL.yyyy"